# Gunicorn with a virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I was doing some work renaming and moving around django projects and I wanted to use virtualenv wrapper instead of leaving the venv in the project directory.

If I run the gunicorn command from the shell then it starts and everything goes fine, but when I do it with `sudo service gunicorn-name start` with the following script it does not run. why would it run from the terminal but not the upstart script?

```
description "Gunicorn daemon for Django project"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on runlevel [!12345]

# If the process quits unexpectadly trigger a respawn
respawn

setuid django
setgid django
chdir /usr/share/nginx/myproj

exec /root/.virtualenvs/myproj/bin/gunicorn \
    --name=langalang \
    --pythonpath=/usr/share/nginx/myproj/myproj \
    --bind=0.0.0.0:9000 \
    --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn-myproj.py \
    myproj.wsgi:application
```

syslog is printing a bunch of this...

```
Aug 19 03:11:30 langalang kernel: [17196647.476140] init: gunicorn-myproj main process ended, respawning
Aug 19 03:11:30 langalang kernel: [17196647.665706] init: gunicorn-myproj main process (16745) terminated with status 1
Aug 19 03:11:30 langalang kernel: [17196647.665721] init: gunicorn-myproj respawning too fast, stopped
```

Comment: It should be returning an error in `/var/log/syslog`. Check that, it should give you a pretty clear pointer as to what's going wrong. Preferably, paste the output of syslog here too.

Comment: can't believe I forgot to check that, was checking my gunicorn logs and nothing was there. I still can't make sense of what they logs are trying to tell me though

Comment: It means that your gunicorn process is dying as soon as it is spawning. So first time it spawns, dies immediately and due to your upstart script `respawns` and then dies immediately. Since it's happening very fast, upstart stops your program all together to save crashes.

Comment: Is there anything else I can look at to track it further?

Comment: Your script seems fine to. I tried it with my project, just changed the directories and `uid` & `gid` to be `vagrant` and `www-data` respectively since that's what I use for my setup. It works fine for me. You can try the same with different user and/or directories. Also you should remove runlevel 1 from your script, it's not gonna be required so there's no need for it to be there, 1 is just single user mode. You're probably never gonna run the system in that mode to deploy.

Comment: ok, it was a permissions issue. IDK why but the logs seems to have reverted to root permissions and then it wasn't able to run under this process. Can you think of any reason why they would change permission on their own

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121342/discussion-between-xk0nsid-and-deltaskelta).